# Average transmission rate on IEEE 802.11 wireless network

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

So, here's the problem:

> An access point is alternately sending L-sized packets to 2 stations,
>   A and B.
>
> The access point is transmitting to A at 10 MBits /s and to B at 2
>   MBit/s.
>
> What's the average rate the access point is transmitting at?

The answer is not 10 + 2 / 2 = 6, but instead it's 3.33 Mbit/s.

How?

Comment: Ask your instructor. (hint: there's more to his answer than is in your question)

Comment: Unfortunattely that will not be possible, since classes are over. Do you know any kind of webpages where I can read and try to figure out the question?

Comment: Resource recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Ok then, so any clue on how to think or what to search?

Comment: You'd have to ask whoever screwed up the math. If it sent 10Mb in the 1st second, and 2Mb in the 2nd second, then over 2sec the *average rate* is 6Mb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an example:

Suppose the frames are 1500 bytes long, it is the same as *12000 bits*.

The transmission of the frame to *A* at 10 Mb/s takes 1.2 milliseconds.

The transmission of the same size frame to *B* takes 6 milliseconds.

In total, to transmit 24000 bits took 7.2 milliseconds. It gives an speed of *3.33 Mb/s*.

The result isn't the arithmetic mean, is the *[Harmonic Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean)*.

The harmonic mean can be expressed as the reciprocal of the arithmetic mean of the reciprocals.

For our case:

=1/(((1/10)+(1/2))/2) =1/((6/10)/2) = (2/1)/(6/10) = 20/6 = 3.33

In general, for two speeds *s1* and *s2* will be:

```
=(2*s1*s2)/(s1+s2)
```

In this case `=(2*10*2)/(10+2) =(40/12) =3,33`